# awk triple files input

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have 3 files, as below:

*File1:*

```
5372,5372,0,0,,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1107,1107,,1.620000,1,2015-08-12,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2110,2110,0,0,,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1601,1601,,9.500000,1,2015-05-29,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
6900,6900,0,0,,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1107,1107,,1.369000,1,2025-09-23,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
8755,8755,0,0,,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1107,1107,,3.232000,1,2025-05-22,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

*File2:*

```
5372,4074,,,,,2,,,
2110,4100,,,,,0,,,
6900,5246,,,,,0,,,
8755,5270,,,,,0,,,
```

*File3:*

```
2187,2500
2188,1500
4227,2000
5270,3000
```

Noting that the `NF` for *File1*, *File2* and *File3* respectively is `47`, `10` and `2`

The needs is to check if the `$23` from *File1* is equal to `2025`, if yes, then convert `$21` to **$21*1000**, then save the $1 in an array. 
After that, get `$2` from *File2* for `$1` that we got from *File1*.

Now we should compare `$21` from *File1* with `$2` from *File3* if the value greater than or equal, print $1 from *File1*.

The expected output for above files:

```
8755
```

I have tried the following code:

```
awk -F"," '{
    if (NF==47) {
        if ($23 ~ /2025/) {$21=$21*1000}
        {A[$1]=$0}
    } else {
        if (NF==10) {
            if (A[$1]==$0) {B[$1]=$0}
        }
        {if (NF==2) {
            B[$1]==$0 && $21>=$2
        }
        {print $0}
    }
}'
```

but the outputs always were *File3*

Please Advise.

Comment: What is `B[$1]==$0 && $23>=$2` supposed to do? It's a comparison expression, but it's not inside `if( ...)`

Comment: @Barmar .. sorry for the mistake, it is $21>=$2 
and it is to compare the value of converted $21 in *File1* with the value of $2 of *File3*, if $21>=$2, I need to get $1 from *File1* for that record.

Comment: But it's not inside an `if`, so it doesn't do anything with the comparison.

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `if(B[$1]==$0 && $21>=$2) { do something }`?

Comment: @Barmar it is an action for the last if statement, isn't it?

Comment: And your final `{print $0}` isn't inside either of the `if` bodies, so it will be done for both file2 and file 3. Is that what you want?

Comment: The actions are supposed to do something, like assign a variable or print. Comparing things without storing the result anywhere doesn't do anything.

Comment: BTW, `$23 ~ /2025/` will also be true if `$23` is `120250`. Use `==` if you want to do an exact match instead of a pattern match.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you anyway, could you please amend the code to do the work described above?

Comment: In the question you said you need to save `$1` in an array. But your code saves `$0` in the array. Which one is right?

Comment: Maybe you actually meant to say that it should save `$21` in the array, using `$1` as the index? Otherwise, how will you compare `$21` to `$2` in file 2?

Comment: I'd like to answer the question with code, but since I can't figure out what you're trying to do, it's hard.

Comment: @Barmar I will explain what I actually need without codes: 
First, the $23 of *File1* is a date, if the YYYY = 2025, I need to convert the $21 (Which is balance) to a lower unit by multiplying it by (1000), then take the $1 for that record, and matching it with $1 from *File2*, now for the matched records, I need to match $2 from *File2* with $1 from *File3*, and compare if $21 from *File1* is >= to $2 from *File3*, if yes, print $1 from *File1*

Comment: Your last step says: "Now we should compare $21 from File1 with $2 from File3 if the value greater than or equal, print $1 from File1." So what was the purpose of file 2 if we're not printing anything from it?

Comment: I think you need to post some real sample input and the desired output. I still can't figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Barmar The purpose from *File2* is to get to link *File1* with *File3*
since $1 from *File3* is not exist in *File1*

Comment: I think you made a mistake in the step I quoted, you meant to say _with $2 from File2_, is that right?

Comment: @Barmar the posted samples are real, but I removed some fields from file1 only, since they are 47!

Comment: I'm still not understanding. The expected output is `8755`. Which line in `File3` links to those lines in `File1` and `File2`?

Comment: I'm starting to see it. File3 `5270,3000` links with File2 `8755,5270`, and that  links with File1 `8755,8755`

Comment: @Barmar, Yes sir ... that's it.

Comment: @Barmar for the example, 8755 has value for $21= 3232, which is greater than 3000 in *File3*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing comes from fact that you count both `,` and `-` as field separators. Additionally `47` as a number of fields in `file1` is very confusing since in actual example there are only 25 fields (even counting `-` as field separator). Anyway, taking your files from question you should write

```
awk -F'[,-]' 'NF==25{ if($23==2025) $21=$21*1000; A[$1]=$21 } 
              NF==10{ B[$2]=$1 }
              NF==2{ if(A[B[$1]]>=$2) print B[$1]}' file1 file2 file3
```

Result:

```
8755
```

---

Change `NF==25` to `NF==47` according to your real case scenario.

Comment: Thanks for  your answer, I made File1 with 25 field only to make it  more convenient, however, I had edited once again to make them 47.

Comment: As I wrote - change `NF==25` to whatever you like, should work in any case, just count fields properly (if `47` doesn't include `-` as field separator then use `49`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk -F',' '
    NF == 47 { A[$1] = $23 ~ /2025/ ? $21*1000 : $21 }
    NF == 10 { B[$2] = $1 }
    NF == 2 && A[B[$1]] >= $2 { print B[$1] }'
```

Comment: This program will print $1 of File3 only.

Comment: Fixed it. I just tested it with your files, it correctly prints `8755`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work, I will try couple of solutions, and update the question. 
Thank you anyway for help.